# How to resolve major function numbers to their name while reversing windows drivers?

Tags: ida, windows, driver, kernel

I'm reversing some windows drivers, and IDA never converts numbers to their corresponding major function name like IRP_MJ_CREATE = 0x00, how can i force this? is there anyway i can convert a number to major function name?

ALSO : why doesn't IDA convert it itself? for the first parameter of IoBuildSynchronousFsdRequest is always a major function number, why can't ida just name its MAJOR function name instead of giving me its number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `M` with your cursor over a symbolic constant; IDA/Hex-Rays will bring up the enum chooser window. From there, type `IRP_MJ_`, and the chooser window should jump to the proper enumeration element.

To have Hex-Rays automatically display function arguments as symbolic constants, change the type of the argument to e.g. `MACRO_IRP_MJ`, or whatever the name of the enumeration is.